# Using the title of the post in a shortcode

Tags: shortcode

Hi I'm trying to use this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-simple-website-screenshot/

I am supposed to use the shortcode: `[screenshot url="www.example.com"]` 
Because I am writing the code in the single.php file I am using:

`<?php echo do_shortcode( '[screenshot url="www.example.com"]' ); ?>`

But, my problem is that the URL is defined in the title of the post, so I tried:

`<?php echo do_shortcode( '[screenshot url="<?php the_title(); ?>"]' ); ?>`

with no luck.

Is it possible to do a workaround on this?

Comment: I need something similar & I can't get my code to work. Please help.

`<?php echo do_shortcode( '[expand title="'.the_title().'"]'.the_content().'[/expand]'); ?>`

Comment: @Elizabeth, Hi could you please post a new question with more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to execute PHP inside a string! Instead, concat the string;

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[screenshot url="' . get_the_title() . '"]' ); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked, I only needed to remove a space "'HERE. get_the_title().

For others: Use `<?php echo do_shortcode( '[screenshot url="'. get_the_title() . '"]' ); ?>`

Comment: That space is for readbility. It won't be included in the final string!!! http://phphowto.blogspot.com/2006/12/concatenate-strings.html

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that  `<?php the_title(); ?>` inside quotation marks doesn't really works
change:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[screenshot url="<?php the_title(); ?>"]' ); ?>
```

to :

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[screenshot url="'.the_title().'"]' ); ?>
```